# Индивидуальные логины и ники в бд

Tags: sql

В базе данных поставил логин и юсернейм индекс UNIQUE, и такая проблема: если регистрировать пользователя с идентичными логин:ник,то в бд ничего не заносится.Но тем же временем идет пробел в id.А если попробовать сменить что-то одно (логин, допустим, оставляем идентичным), то такие данные уже заносятся в бд.А мне надо, чтобы ни логин, ни ник не совпадал ни разу.Т.е., полностью индивидуальные данные.Подскажите, как сделать, а то я слоупок ещё)

Comment: два отдельных уникальных индекса. один на логин, второй на ник. А на id не обращайте внимание, пропуски это не страшно

Comment: Поубивал бы всех, кто не позволяет дублировать ник. Из-за таких сволочей вечно приходится придумывать что-то идиотское, вместо нормального Sergey

Answer (score 1):

Я не очень понял вопроса и проблемы, но всё же попытаюсь ответить: чтобы id не было пустым стоит его сразу сделать `auto_increment` и не трогать, а логин и ник сделать уникальными `NOT NULL`. Ниже логин я заменил на email.

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id          int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    email       varchar(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    username    varchar(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Пример на PHP ниже. Я предположил, что тебе надо сделать какую-нибудь форму входа в виде: "Введите логин или email".

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
$sql = "SELECT id,username,email FROM users WHERE username like 'vasya' OR email like 'vasya@example.com' LIMIT 1";
$st = $conn->query($sql);
if($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $id = (int) $row['id'];
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверяй напрямую через php, или что ты там используешь:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "userpwd", "dbname");

$login = "login_test";
$login = $db->real_escape_string($login); // не обязательно. только при $_GET И $_POST
$username = "username_test";
$username = $db->real_escape_string($username); // не обязательно. только при $_GET И $_POST

$table = "test"; // имя таблицы, в которой нужно проверить то, что ты хочешь

if($db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$table."` WHERE `login` = '".$login."' AND `username` = '".$username."'") == 0) {
  // если нету идентичной записи
} else {
  // если есть
}
?>
```

Comment: между `$num_rows = $db->query(...)` и `if($num_rows == 0) {...` есть промежуток времени малый, в который тем не менее параллельный запрос может успеть совершить регистрацию пользователя точно с таким же логином и/или ником. Более вредного совета трудно представить.